# Use multiple svn repositories in a project

Tags: svn

Is it possible to use multiple svn repositories in one project.
Lets say I have a framework repository and multiple modules repositories.

In my project I will be using the framework and those modules and when that framework repo is updated I need to be able to sync it with that in my project. Same with the modules.

Comment: Could you clarify why you should want to use multiple svn repositories? There are more disadvantages, if used in the same project by the same people. If you have to, [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals) is the only solution. The help file gives examples how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% clear on what you are trying to do, but you may want to look up the [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals) property.  If another folder in the repository is specified as an external of the folder you are checking out, it will be be included in the working directory after an svn update, and can be committed along with the remainder of the contents of the working directory.

I have done this regularly with seperate folders in a single svn repository tree.  If that is what you mean, using svn:externals could be helpful for you.  I have never tried to specify a folder from a totally different svn repository or server, so if that is what you want to do, I am not sure if svn:externals will work for you.  You could always try.